# update multiple svn projects in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

Is it possible to update multiple svn projects in eclipse in one action? Lets say they all in same folder and in same svn.

I know how to do it using external tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Subclipse you can select those projects and invoke Team / Update to HEAD. Subversive has similar action.

Alternatively, you can setup new synchronization in Synchronize view and use update all action from the view toolbar. The major advantage of this approach is that you can review incoming changes before updating your workspace.